# Отправка данных с Form1 на Form2

Tags: c#

Привет.

Вот ещё 1 вопросик: нужно сделать так, чтобы, например, вводим в textbox  слово и нажимаем на кнопку - нас перекидывает на вторую форму, и там написано "Вы вошли как..." и имя из техтбокса из первой формы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форма 1 (Отправка)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace posted
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
            f.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Форма 2(Прием)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace posted
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(string text)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text += text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Опасно, но можно создать отдельный класс (например, Static) для статических переменных, передаваемых через формы, и хранить их там.
Класс Static

```
static public string login;
```

Форма 1:

```
Static.login = textBox1.Text;
```

Форма 2:

```
textBox2.Text = Static.login;
```

**Но со статическими переменными надо быть очень аккуратным!**