# Как передать данные из формы в другую форму?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имеется код, который делает на форме2 100 текстбоксов, боксы заполняются '+', затем количество данных плюсов высчитывается для каждой строки. номер строки и количество плюсов - исходные данные для формы3, на который будет график Chart. Не пойму как передать в форму3 данные, чтобы использовать их для графика.

```
namespace VKR
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public int Nx = 40, Ny = 28;
        public int Loc_x = 3, Loc_y = 3, Sw = 35, Sh = 20;
        public static int iLimit = 10, iVariable = 10;
        public int counter = 0;
        public int[] count;
        public TextBox[,] tbArray;
        public Label[] lbArray_exp;
        public Label[] lbArray_V;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Create(iLimit, iVariable);

        }

        public void Create(int lim, int var)
        {
            tbArray = new TextBox[lim, var];
            lbArray_exp = new Label[var];
            lbArray_V = new Label[var];
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++, Loc_y += Ny)
            {
                Loc_x = 3;
                //
                lbArray_V[i] = new Label();
                lbArray_V[i].Name = "label_V" + i;
                lbArray_V[i].Text = string.Format("{0}", (i + 1) * 10);
                lbArray_V[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
                lbArray_V[i].Location = new Point(0, Loc_y);
                //
                panel3.Controls.Add(lbArray_V[i]);
                //
                for (int j = 0; j < var; j++, Loc_x += Nx)
                {
                    tbArray[i, j] = new TextBox();
                    tbArray[i, j].Name = "TextBoxx" + j;
                    tbArray[i, j].Size = new Size(Sw, Sh);
                    tbArray[i, j].Location = new Point(Loc_x, Loc_y);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(tbArray[i, j]);
                    //
                    lbArray_exp[j] = new Label();
                    lbArray_exp[j].Name = string.Format("exp_", j);
                    lbArray_exp[j].Text = string.Format("Экс.{0}", j + 1);
                    lbArray_exp[j].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                    lbArray_exp[j].Location = new Point(Loc_x - 65, 0);
                    panel2.Controls.Add(lbArray_exp[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            //
            btn.Name = "btn1";
            btn.Text = "Обработать";
            btn.Size = new Size(80, 25);
            btn.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width - 5, this.ClientSize.Height - btn.Height - 5);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            //
            foreach (TextBox tb in panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                tb.KeyPress += textBox_KeyPress;
            }
            btn.Click += btn1_Click;
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 form3 = new Form3();

            //
            string[] str = new string[iLimit];
            int[] count = new int[iLimit];
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < iLimit; i++, counter = 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < iVariable; j++)
                {
                    if (tbArray[i, j].TextLength >1)
                    {

                        tbArray[i, j].Text = "+";
                    }

                    if (tbArray[i, j].Text == "+")
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }

                }
                count[i] = counter/iLimit;
            }
            form3.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();
        }


        private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyChar != '+' && e.KeyChar != (char)8)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ошибка ввода");
                e.KeyChar = new char();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Еще: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395544/

Comment: @andreycha: С недавнего времени можно добавить прямо в сообщение о закрытии (там есть кнопка «править»).

Comment: @VladD о, спасибо, не знал!